# How to add rows with unique column to the database?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a table with unique column, it consists of 8 characters of random English letters and numbers.

I need to be able to seed the table by adding more data to the existing data.
I am supposed to enter a given amount of rows.
I tried using Factories and Seeders but then realized it's not working as expected:

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Models;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 

    class Code extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'codes';
    }
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'code',
        'is_valid'
    ];
```

**Factory:**

```
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'code' => $this->faker->regexify('[A-Z0-9]{8}')
    ];
}
```

Then I am supposed to add data by running:

```
$codes = Code::factory()->count(10000)->create();
```

and after that, if I run it multiple times I might end up with constraint violation:

```
// add some more data
$codes = Code::factory()->count(10000)->create();
$codes = Code::factory()->count(10000)->create();
```

What is an efficient way to be able to add given amount of rows and make sure they're unique?

All other questions I've seen here are similar, but not working for my case.

Comment: please share model code as well

Comment: Added, it's a simple model of codes

Answer (score 1):

Change in your factory definition this line from this: `'code' => $this->faker->regexify('[A-Z0-9]{8}')`  to: `$faker->unique()->regexify('[A-Z0-9]{8}');`.

Answer (score 1):

In your factory you can use the unique() faker modifier : https://fakerphp.github.io/#modifiers

```
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'code' => $this->faker->unique()->regexify('[A-Z0-9]{8}')
    ];
}
```

**Edit:** when running the factory with existing data, you can check if the faked data already exists in the database like:

```
public function definition()
{
    do {
        $fakeCode = $this->faker->unique()->regexify('[A-Z0-9]{8}');
    } while (DB::table('codes')->where('code', $fakeCode)->exists());

    return [
        'code' => $fakeCode
    ];
}
```

Comment: I used it originally, but it should not work since I create more data on top of existing one. From what I understand, it makes it unique in the dataset it creates, but it can still conflict with what's inside the database?

Comment: Yep, it can still conflict with what's already inside the database. You can check if the value from faker already exists in the database and if so provide a different value